# Export report to XHTML format with JasperReports Server

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I need to export report in format XHTML with help of *JasperReports Server*.

I'm using a Url like: `http://localhost:8080/JasperReports/report?_repName=test&_repFormat=pdf&_dataSource=default&_outFilename=myTest.pdf&_repLocale=es_DO&_repE
ncoding=UTF-8`.

I can export to many formats (pdf, html, xls, ...) but i can't get how to export to XHTML format. Just changing value for parameter `_repFormat=xhtml` not working.

It works in *iReport* preview, but not via *JR Server's* url.

I can't get anything useful in neither Jasper documentation and the web forums.

Comment: Are you talking about *JasperReports Server*?

Comment: JasperReports Server running on tomcat 7.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the answer outlined here: http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/531694/xhtml-render-or-export

Comment: I had seen this solution, however note that this solution applies to export from Java and I need to export using a request from the browser.